# Call same function on multiple urls django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

urls.py

```
 url(r'^level/ajax/reload/$', views.ajax_change_status, 
 name='ajax_change_status'),
 url(r'^level/(\d+)/ajax/reload/$', views.ajax_change_status, 
 name='ajax_change_status'),
 url(r'^level/(\d+)/(\d+)/ajax/reload/$', views.ajax_change_status, 
 name='ajax_change_status'),
```

In my urls.py i have these urls.Im trying to call an ajax function in my view basically to update the notification badge to 0 after user clicks on the bell icon.The notification badge is in the base.html template.Im calling the url with the name "ajax_change_status" . I want all these urls to call the same ajax funtion.Is it possible to do this or is there a better way?Im getting a 500 server error when i click on the bell icon from the second and third url

My ajax function in views.py:

```
def ajax_change_status(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
   try:
     Notification.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
     .update(viewed=True)
     Addnotify.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
     .update(viewed=True)
     FollowNotify.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
     .update(viewed=True)
     HubNotify.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)
     .update(viewed=True)
    return JsonResponse({"success": True})
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      return JsonResponse({"success": False})
```

My ajax jquery:

```
var clicks = 0;

 $("#notify").on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/reload/',
    data: {
     },

    success: function (data) {

      if (data.success) {
                    console.log('ajax call  success.');

        $('#badge').html('0')
        $('#headnotify').html('NOTIFICATIONS (0)')
        // here you update the HTML to change the active to inactive
      }else{
        console.log('ajax call not success.');
      }
    clicks++;
    }
    });
   });
```

Seems like it is not getting into the ajax function when i try it on the second and third url!!

Comment: did you try setting different 'name' to those urls?

Comment: I am not doing this since the bell Icon is placed in the base.html and all pages are extending this base and I can call only one name

Comment: This question is not very clear. If you've got a single JS script, why do you need multiple URLs at all? Especially if they all do exactly the same thing. What is the point of this?

Comment: Multiple urls because i want it working for all the urls im on and js file url parameter simply concarnates the urls right..But i got it working anywany!thanks @DanielRoseman

Comment: It only concatenates because you don't start your Ajax URL with a leadlng slash. If you did that `url: '/ajax/reload/',` they would all go to the same place.

Comment: okay @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of those urls should have different names. It's going to be pain to allow for optional url arguments. You'll be much better off (and more sane) if you just name them differently. Your view function probably should allow for those to be passed in though, otherwise what's the purpose of them?

```
def ajax_change_status(request, param1=None, param2=None):
    ...
```

And personally I like using keyword arguments as it better explains the url path, but that's up to you.